# how to remove the table cell separator with a background color

Tags: html, css, xpages

I have this code in an XPage but when it displays there is a white line between each table cell. Using HTML or ?? how do I get rid of the serarator?

```
<xp:table border="0">
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td style="width:25%" styleClass="wfsBlue">
                <xp:image url="/Logo200.gif" id="image1"></xp:image></xp:td>
            <xp:td style="width:24.0%" styleClass="wfsBlue"></xp:td>
            <xp:td style="width:24.0%" styleClass="wfsBlue"></xp:td>
            <xp:td style="width:25.0%" styleClass="wfsBlue">Workflo Systems</xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
</xpTable>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your table the CSS style like

```
table {
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Or (the hard way): define the attribute cellspacing="0"

Comment: The Table css setting works like a charm. Thanks Oliver.